Nump's arange with float gives inconsistent values
Numpy's arange is sometimes cropping the last value in the iteration when creating an array of floats and sometimes it does not. The behavior is inconsistent and seems bizarre to me. Can anybody make sense of this? If it's not clear, I'm trying to generate an array from 35.33 down to 35.13 in -0.01 intervals.
GOOD
>>> x=np.arange(35.33, 35.12, -.01)
>>> x
array([35.33, 35.32, 35.31, 35.3 , 35.29, 35.28, 35.27, 35.26, 35.25,
       35.24, 35.23, 35.22, 35.21, 35.2 , 35.19, 35.18, 35.17, 35.16,
       35.15, 35.14, 35.13, 35.12])
>>> len(x)
22

BAD
>>> x=np.arange(35.33, 35.13, -.01)
>>> x
array([35.33, 35.32, 35.31, 35.3 , 35.29, 35.28, 35.27, 35.26, 35.25,
       35.24, 35.23, 35.22, 35.21, 35.2 , 35.19, 35.18, 35.17, 35.16,
       35.15, 35.14])
>>> len(x)
20

Python 3.12.4 (tags/v3.12.4:8e8a4ba, Jun  6 2024, 19:30:16) [MSC v.1940 64 bit (AMD64)]
Name: numpy
Version: 1.26.4


If you want floating point ranges, multiply an integer range by a scaling factor yourself or use np.linspace

Doesn't the arange docs say something about the problems with floats?  What's this 'narange'?

@hpaulj Where I come from, 'narange' is what we call a "brain fart."

@MadPhysicist linspace worked for me thx
